# After deploying in Azure WebSites - Not able to trace the code inside the Startup->Configuration(IAppBuilder app) method

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

Our application uses the **Azure Active Directory** for authentication and save the token into the database, local application with local DB works fine and even local application with Azure db works fine but after deploying to the **azure-website** its failing to save to db(may be).

**Here I am not able to trace the code written inside Startup->Configuration(IAppBuilder app)....break point never hits this function but this gets executed.**

I followed [Adding Azure Active Directory and OWIN Code into an AngularJS/ASP.NET MVC Application to Handle User Authentication](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/adding-azure-active-directory-and-owin-code-into-an-angularjs-asp-net-mvc-application-to-handle-user-authentication)

Exception is:

```
{
   "message":"An error has occurred.",
   "exceptionMessage":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: token",
   "exceptionType":"System.ArgumentNullException",
   "stackTrace":"   at Microsoft.Azure.TokenCloudCredentials
```

Comment: After tracing the deployed website - i come to know that its not at all hitting the "Startup.cs" page where generally i authenticate and save to the DB..

Comment: Are there any settings or environment variables you have set on your local application which might not have gotten transferred to the web app?

Comment: Hi Zain...I have deployed another app to the azure with the Invoke method inside Startup Class, but again breakpoint hits the Invoke method but not the Configuration method.

Comment: Sunil, there isn't enough information here for me to help you. I have no idea what your code looks like, or what your Configuration method is or what it's like.  Can you please create a minimum solution that reproduces this error and share that here? Also, take a look at this article about how to ask good questions on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, now that you know the problem is that your code doesn't hit the Startup.cs page, update your question's title and body to better reflect the actual error you're seeing. That'll help other people find your question and answer it